# Access to ForeingKey's model data in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to access to a ForeignKey's model data, but I don't know how. I wrote this as a simple example of what I want to do:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
phone_number = models.BigIntegerField()

class Model2(models.Model):
model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = model1.name
phone_number = model1.phone_number
```

It gives me the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `model1.name` it aims to obtain the attribute of a `ForeignKey` object, not the object that is referenced by the `ForeignKey` of a model *object*.

You can define two properties to obtain the `.name` and the `.phone_number` of the related `Model1` object:

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.model1.name
    
    @property
    def phone_number(self):
        return self.model1.phone_number
```